# If $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ for $x>0$, show that $\{x∈[0,1]; f(x)>0\}$ is measurable and compute its measure

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ for $x>0$,  show that $A=\{x∈[0,1]; f(x)>0\}$ is measurable and compute the measure of $A$.

I prove measurable by the following:
From definition of cantor set, we know $[0,1]-k = ⋃i=1(Ik)$
$\{Ik\}$ is a sequence of open interval $I, Ik$ are disjoint open intervals
Thus, $A = Uk=1(Ik[0,xk]) =Uk=1(Ak)$
each Ak is a cube, so A is measurable
I am not sure it's correct or not
and don't know how to compute it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, $A$ is an open set, hence measurable. Note $\sin(1/x) > 0$ if and only if $\dfrac{1}{\pi} < x \le 1$ or there is some positive integer $n$ for which $\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)\pi} < x < \dfrac{1}{2n\pi}$. It follows that

$$A = \left(\frac{1}{\pi},1\right]\cup\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}, \frac{1}{2n\pi}\right)$$

The union above is a disjoint union, so the measure of $A$ is

$$1 - \frac{1}{\pi} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{2n\pi} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}\right]$$

which you can show sums to $1-\dfrac{\log 2}{\pi}$.

Comment: Is "f  is continuous, AA is an open set, hence measurable" a theorem?

Comment: @梁楷葳 open sets are Borel sets and Borel sets are Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Notice how $x\cdot\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)>0 \forall x\in\left(\frac{1}{\pi},1\right]$, you seem to have missed out adding the measure of that set. According to me the answer should be $1-\frac{\ln(2)}{\pi}$

Comment: @noobie yes, that is correct. Thanks for the comment.